# How to create a list of a number?

Tags: python, list, numbers

I am new to python and i was wondering how i could create a list of numbers in python as such

```
number = 123456
list_to_be_created = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: `list(map(int, str(number)))` >> `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> list(range(1, 7))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

If you literally have the number 123456 (i.e. the `int` value for *one hundred twenty three thousand four hundred fifty six*) and you want to turn it into a list of its digits, you might do:

```
>>> number = 123456
>>> list_to_be_created = list(map(int, str(number)))
>>> list_to_be_created
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a list comprehension:

```
number = 123456
print([int(x) for x in str(number)])
```

Returns:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```